# Simple Graph Degree Sequence Proof

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Let G be a simple graph with degree sequence $(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$. Prove that for each *k*, $0<k<n$:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k d_i\le k(k-1)+\sum_{i=k+1}^n min(k,d_i)$$

I'm new to graph theory and proof writing. I'm not sure I even understand what this question is asking. Can anyone help explain what I am trying to prove?

I know that the degree sequence describes the degree (number of edges) associated with each vertex.

To prove this, could I assume the opposite is true and use a contradictory approach? So, assume $\sum_{i=1}^k d_i> k(k-1)+\sum_{i=k+1}^n min(k,d_i)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^k d_i$ counts the total number of edges incident to the first $k$ vertices (counting them twice if they are incident to two of the vertices). What's the largest number of edges there can be?

Let's split the edges into two groups: those between two of the first $k$ vertices (which get counted twice) and those from one of the other vertices to one of the first $k$ (which only get counted once).

For the first type, the most edges that each of the $k$ vertices could have is to all $k-1$ others, giving the term $k(k-1)$.

For the second type, let's count the most edges which could come from vertices $k+1,\dots,n$ back to the first $k$ vertices. The are at most $k$ such edges from each of those vertices—if it's adjacent to every single one of the first $k$—or, if its degree $d_i$ is smaller, then there can be at most $d_i$ edges.

Put these together and you have your upper bound.